# replacement for AuthenticationException.getAuthentication()

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, openid

following scenario

- we have a login form with a openid button
- all users can login eigther with user/passwd or openid
- when a user tries to login with openid and doesn't have a account he is redirected to a registration form
- this works very well with spring-security 3.x, but will not work with the upcoming 4.x release, because the AuthenticationException.getAuthentication() method is removed

what we allready tried:

- replace the failurehandler with a successhandler but that leads to a UserNameNotFoundException in the OpenId-UserDetailService, so that the handler isn't called
- implement the redirection in the OpenId-UserDetailService, but here we have no access to the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse

here comes the actual 3.x working code

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class OpenIDAuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler implements OpenIDAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Nonnull
    private final NormalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder normalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public OpenIDAuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl(@Nullable final NormalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder normalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder) {
        Assert.notNull(normalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder);
        this.normalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder = normalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder;
    }

    private static void sessionShouldBePresent(@Nullable final HttpSession session) throws ServletException {
        if (session == null) {
            log.error("No Session found");
            throw new ServletException("No session found");
        }
    }

    private static boolean openIdAuthenticationSuccessfulButUserIsNotRegistered(@Nullable final AuthenticationException exception) {
        return exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException &&
                exception.getAuthentication() instanceof OpenIDAuthenticationToken &&
                OpenIDAuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS == getOpenIdAuthenticationToken(exception).getStatus();
    }

    private static OpenIDAuthenticationToken getOpenIdAuthenticationToken(@Nonnull final AuthenticationException exception) {
        return (OpenIDAuthenticationToken) exception.getAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (openIdAuthenticationSuccessfulButUserIsNotRegistered(exception)) {
            redirectToOpenIdRegistrationUrl(request, response, exception);
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        }
    }

    private void redirectToOpenIdRegistrationUrl(@Nonnull final HttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull final HttpServletResponse response, @Nonnull final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
        addOpenIdAttributesToSession(request, getOpenIdAuthenticationToken(exception));
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/signup");
    }

    private void addOpenIdAttributesToSession(@Nonnull final HttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull final OpenIDAuthenticationToken openIdAuthenticationToken) throws ServletException {
        final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        sessionShouldBePresent(session);
        final NormalizedOpenIdAttributes normalizedOpenIdAttributes = normalizedOpenIdAttributesBuilder.build(openIdAuthenticationToken);
        session.setAttribute(OPENID_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, normalizedOpenIdAttributes);
    }
}
```

websecurity configuration class

```java
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private OpenIDAuthenticationFailureHandler openIDAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private OpenIDAuthenticationUserDetailsService openIDAuthenticationUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/check")
                .permitAll();

        http.logout()
                .permitAll();

        http.exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/denied");

        http.openidLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/openid")
                .failureUrl("/login/failure")
                .failureHandler(openIDAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .authenticationUserDetailsService(openIDAuthenticationUserDetailsService)
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

this implementation is based on the code from this http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/spring-security-by-example-openid-login.html

any suggestions what we can else try to be compatible with spring-security 4.x. we also searched the internet, but all what we found is not working with spring-security 4.x

Comment: Not that this will help much, but someone made a comment at the very bottom of that page explaining a potential solution to the problem: http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/spring-security-by-example-openid-login.html?showComment=1369334442380#c1072711203002013824

Comment: I have the same problem. What is the replacement???

Comment: Is there any update on this, were you able to find a solution @BigMichi1

Comment: Didn't found a solution yet